# Create a loop to call php function and echo from that function on same html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a simple webapp sort of thing that will send push notifications to my clients on button click. Here is a sample page that i have created[image]

I have a file named as `sendPush.php`

On button click i want to send a push notification which will be echoed as

```
Notifications sent:

"Notification sent to userId : xxxX"
"Notification sent to userId : xxxX"
"Notification sent to userId : xxxX"
"Notification sent to userId : xxxX"
```

I want to send notifis to all 147 users. Now here is my php code for button click

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sendNotif() 
    {
         alert('ok');
    } 

</script>

<div class="content">

    <input type="button" value="Click to Send" onClick="sendNotif();">
    <br />
    <br />
    <label for="push">Notifications sent: </label>

</div>
```

The problem here i am facing is, i have php function in same app named as sendNotification() that will send notification and echo the result. But I am not sure how can i make a loop of this php function in javascript inside javascript function

```
function sendNotif() 
        {
            // LOOP HERE
        }
```

If `$clients` is the list of my clients, how can i send notif to all in a loop using php function in same page as `sendNotification($client)`

MOdified

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var lastIdCount = 0;

    function sendNotif() 
    {
       var clients = "<?php echo $clients; ?>";
       var getPath = "push.php?clientId=".concat(clients['lastIdCount']);
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: getPath,
            task: "save",
            data: { 
                ajax: "true",
            },
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function( msg ) 
        {
            alert('ok');
            if( msg.status=="1") 
            {        
                alert('okasdf');
                lastIdCount++;
                sendNotif();
        }
        else 
        {
                alert("Error : "+msg.error);
            }
        }); 
    } 

</script>
```

In push.php

sample

```
$resp = array();
    $resp['error'] = 'Invalid Request';
    $resp['status'] = '0';
    $resp['data'] = '0';
```

Comment: I think you need while or for for loop, in case you just change lastIdCount, and there won't be a repeatable thing.. etc: while(lastIdCount < clients){ ... }

Comment: well i will add but the code does nothing, there is no alert on completion !!

Comment: @Muhammad Umar looks like youre trying to do a separate ajax post for each client.  It would be much more efficient if you packed all clients into request data and send all of them to the server at once.  than have server deal with each notification and return status for each one back to you in an array.  There is lots of overhead to deal with when u make so many separate requests

Comment: Yeah, he could. It would best solution.

Comment: The problem is sending push to one person will take a 10-20 seconds and sending 100 will take some time, i can't make user see blank screen till then. hOWVER my piece of code is not working, is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: var clients = "<?php echo $clients; ?>";  @DonnyLive what is wrong in this?

Comment: depends on where and how placed? is your file in php? Try to look at this place of code via source. If it's number - there shouldn't be problem.

Comment: its an array. I am trying to pass array in php to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first to get all clients you want to send notification and use them ID's for setInterval or setTimeout functions which would repeat your queries. Probably you should

get_clients.php

```
<?php
    $clients_array = array(1,2,6,15,29); /// let's say ID's you got from SQL or w/e you need.
    echo json_encode($clients_array); // [1,2,6,15,29]
?>
```

send_for_client.php

```
<?php
    $id = isset($_POST['id'])?$_POST['id']:false;
    if($id){
        // do some code you need
        echo "Notification sent for id: ".$id;
    }
?>
```

index.html

```
...
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(){
        $.post('get_clients.php',{},function(cid){ 
            obj = JSON.parse(cid);
            var cids = obj;
            /// cids is array of clients. so, you can do like:
            var i = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                if(cids.length > i){
                    $.post('send_for_client.php',{id:cids[i]},function(resp){
                        $("#result").append(resp+"<br />");
                        i++;
                    });
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            },100);

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="send" type="submit" name="button" value="Send notifications" />
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
...
```

I'm not tested this think, however it should work or simply show idea how you could try to find a solution for your problem. Have in mind this code can have mistakes so.. don't be lazy to check them out, not even do copy/paste :)

I hope it helped even a bit.

Comment: Take a look at my fixed code. I've tested it and worked fine, so setInterval is one of your solutions or sent all notifications in PHP, and just show all PHP results in your page.

Answer (score 1):

javascript and php are run in 2 different places.  Your javascript runs in a browser while your php runs on the server.  You cant really mix those two.

The way you probably want to do this is, on button click capture the click with javascript and  send ajax request to your php script sitting on the server. Than have the php perform push notifications.  Once php script is done, return result back to javascript to show it to the user.

You should also use javascript library like jquery which makes things much easier (especially the ajax call).

Comment: I'm fully agree with you.

Comment: yes that's what i am asking, the problem is, i want to show the result of each push sent. And i am not sure how to perform this query in a loop. which way sould be efficient. Or if there is a way i can directly link my button click to trigger the php function.

Comment: Well your php function HAS to run on the server.  That being said the only way to trigger that function is make a request to the server to run it.  And the best way in your case to make that request is to make an ajax call to the server to run the function. Once u make the ajax request to the server, your php function will run the loop and store results in an array for sake of simplicity.  Once all notifications are sent out your php script on the server will send the response back to the javascript. Now your java script can show the results to the user.

Comment: @MikeWu Can you please have a look at my modified code?